# Convert System.Array to string[]

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, system.array

I have a System.Array that I need to convert to string[]. Is there a better way to do this than just looping through the array, calling ToString on each element, and saving to a string[]? The problem is I don't necessarily know the type of the elements until runtime.

Comment: Without knowing the types until runtime, you essentially need to iterate over the array (be it with LINQ or whatever method).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

How about using LINQ?

```
string[] foo = someObjectArray.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: I don't seem to have access to the .Select method from my Array. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, add `System.Linq` to your `using`

Comment: Make sure you are using C# 3, and that you've included the System.Linq namespace.

Comment: I have System.Linq in my using statements. Here is the error message I get: 
Error 1 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Craig, TheHurt, and LBushkin: `System.Array` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, so most LINQ extensions won't work.  There is, however, an `OfType<T>` extension method on `IEnumerable` (which `System.Array` *does* implement), so it would have to be `string[] foo = someArray.OfType<object>().Select(o=>o.ToString()).ToArray();`.

Comment: You also need `System.Collections.Generic` in your `using` for `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Updated thanks to P Daddy; I forgot that `System.Array` is unusual.

Comment: How would this be modified to ensure System.Array elements w/ null are maintained in the new string[]?

Answer (score 14):

Is it just `Array`? Or is it (for example) `object[]`? If so:

```
object[] arr = ...
string[] strings = Array.ConvertAll<object, string>(arr, Convert.ToString);
```

Note than any 1-d array of reference-types should be castable to `object[]` (even if it is actually, for example, `Foo[]`), but value-types (such as `int[]`) can't be. So you could try:

```
Array a = ...
object[] arr = (object[]) a;
string[] strings = Array.ConvertAll<object, string>(arr, Convert.ToString);
```

But if it is something like `int[]`, you'll have to loop manually.

Comment: It is just Array and it could actually contain value types (probably will).

Comment: @KrisTrip - the *variable* might be "just Array", but the object won't be; it has a definite array type. There is also a **big** difference between "contain value types" (which `object[]` can do), and "is a value-type array" (such as `int[]`). This difference matters in this case. Can you clarify what **exactly** the `Array` instance is?

Comment: I get the Array by using a ToArray method. I don't know until runtime but it could be an int[], double[], float[], string[], or Complex[] (user defined object)

Comment: In that case, either you'll have to loop manually (like you are) or do some pretty messy reflection (`MakeGenericMethod`). The former would be preferable.

Comment: +1 for `object[] arr = (object[]) a;` as simple as it can be.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Array.ConvertAll`, like this:

```
string[] strp = Array.ConvertAll<int, string>(arr, Convert.ToString);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple and basic approach;

```
Array personNames = Array.CreateInstance(typeof (string), 3);
// or Array personNames = new string[3];
personNames.SetValue("Ally", 0);
personNames.SetValue("Eloise", 1);
personNames.SetValue("John", 2);

string[] names = (string[]) personNames; 
// or string[] names = personNames as string[]

foreach (string name in names)
    Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Or just an another approach: You can use `personNames.ToArray` too:

```
string[] names = (string[]) personNames.ToArray(typeof (string));
```

Comment: The second approach looks cool and it was the 1st thing I tried but it does not exist in .NET 6.

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be compressed, but it gets around the limitation of not being able to use Cast<> or Linq Select on a System.Array type of object.

```
Type myType = MethodToGetMyEnumType();
Array enumValuesArray = Enum.GetValues(myType);
object[] objectValues new object[enumValuesArray.Length];
Array.Copy(enumValuesArray, objectValues, enumValuesArray.Length);

var correctTypeIEnumerable = objectValues.Select(x => Convert.ChangeType(x, t));
```

Comment: Still an array of generic objects.