# Get Enum values as string array

Tags: c#

I want to get all `Enum.values` as `string[]`.

I tryed using

```
Array mPriorityVals = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MPriority));
```

But how do I cast it as `string[]`?

Comment: Can you be more clear? You need enum names or values (1,2,3)?

Comment: Since you have already `System.Array`, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970738/convert-system-array-to-string

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need [Enum.GetNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, [Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gives the result as EnumType rather than string.

```
string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof (MPriority));
```

I suggest you to just use `GetNames`, don't call `GetValues` and cast it to string as suggested in comment.